# Cyberpunk 2020 Reflex question

Tags: cyberpunk-2020

I am fairly new to running Cyberpunk 2020, and wanted to make sure I am doing this right.  On the PC sheet, Reflex is divided by a '/' mark. I assume it is for modifiers to the ability. Is this correct?

Answer (score 14):

It is intended for conditionally boosted reflexes, which is the on and off values for the Sandevistan speedware if you have it. Of course, at some point I guess everyone nerfs the reflex boosters into "initiative only" and write the initiative value there as Xabei said.

Comment: Well, it is explicitly written in the rules that Sandevistan and Kerenzikov only add to Initiative. For real REF adds, you have to get the Adrenal Booster, or go to space or Europe for some exclusive treatments.

Comment: Xabei, which edition of the book do you have?

Comment: Reads as such (initiative for Sandevistan and boosterware) in mine (2nd edition)

Comment: I have version 2.01, the one with the new artwork. A huge visual step down. :)

Comment: Yeah, the new artwork sucks. There was no mention of "initiative only" for boosterware in the original edition, so we had assumed that to be a reflex booster.

Comment: Lucky you! Our GM did not let us, so we had to pay heavy money for Deep Space and Eurozone nanos and genetics modifications. But in the end, we cybered up enough anyway. :)

Comment: I was the GM, and I ended up nerfing it as well. Too much for too cheap otherwise.

Answer (score 8):

AFAIK, it is for cases when REF differs for initiative and skill resolution (e.g. Sandevistan and Kerenzikov boosts).

Answer (score 6):

I believe that certain kinds of armor also involve a REF penalty, so the slash would divide you into armored/unarmored REF. But a true 'punk is never going without armor, neh?